# Why can't I retrieve data from historian in Bluemix Watson IoT Platform ?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot, historian

For the past week, I get error message http 503 when trying to query historical data one for one of my devices. Previously this was working and the application has not been modified. The device has not been changed. The data is correctly supplied (according to dashboard).

Has IBM changed the interface or the service has been disabled? The solution worked for over a month without error.

What can cause historical data in Bluemix Watson IoT Platform to not be accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier this month,  the "built-in" historian feature for Watson-IoT was withdrawn. Please use the last value cache to access the most recent events from a device.

In addition to the last value cache, the old timeseries historian has been replaced by a managed connector from Watson IoT Platform to the IBM Cloudant NoSQL DB service on Bluemix.

See these blog posts for more details:

[Notice of withdrawal of the ‘built-in’ Time Series historian component of IBM Watson IoT Platform](https://developer.ibm.com/iotplatform/2016/07/27/notice-of-withdrawal-of-the-built-in-historian-component-of-ibm-watson-iot-platform/)

[Enhanced data storage capabilities for IBM Watson IoT Platform](https://developer.ibm.com/iotplatform/2016/07/25/enhanced-data-storage-capabilities-for-ibm-watson-iot-platform/)